# mysql recursive(tree) parent child category

Tags: mysql, sql, database, recursion

I am new in mysql. This is my table:

category table:

```
id | name        | prent
----------------------------
1  |  os         | null
2  | linux       | 1
3  | ubuntu      | 2
4  | xubuntu     | 3
5  | lubuntu     | 3
6  | zubuntu     | 3
7  | zubuntu 2   | 6
8  | suse        | 2
9  | fedora      | 2
10 | windowse    | 1
11 | windowse xp | 10
12 | windowse 7  | 10
13 | windowse 8  | 10
14 | food        | null
15 | dance       | null
```

Each category has a parent and I want to prepare them to show in a drop-down menu.

This is what I want to get:

```
id | name          | depth
----------------------------
1  | os            | 0
2  | -linux        | 1
3  | --ubuntu      | 2
4  | ---xubuntu    | 3
5  | ---lubuntu    | 3
6  | ---zubuntu    | 3
7  | ----zubuntu 2 | 4
8  | --suse        | 2
9  | --fedora      | 2
10 | -windows      | 1
11 | --windows  xp | 2
12 | --windows  7  | 2
13 | --windows  8  | 2
14 | food          | 0
15 | dance         | 0
```

Here, categories are not in order and my code has to provide order for children categories far from their parents. Indentation before name is provided based on depth of parents of each category. There is no limit for number of children of each category however the total number of categories will not exceed 100.

Is there any query that gives such result? I prefer a query that can be run in form of [active record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) in a PHP framework.

Comment: no. mysql doesn't support recursive queries. you'll have to do an iterative loop in your code to work your way down the tree.

Comment: Did you look here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633497/mysql-how-to-query-parent-child?rq=1

Comment: @EdManet, how about the number of depth more than one and two?

Comment: @MarcB, how to use iterative loop doing such action?

Comment: `while($not_done) { do_more_queries(); }` basically. the code is up to you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [***Thread***](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161) led me. Thanks to @RolandoMySQLDBA

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetAncestry` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetAncestry` (GivenID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE rv VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE cm CHAR(1);
    DECLARE ch INT;

    SET rv = '';
    SET cm = '';
    SET ch = GivenID;
    WHILE ch > 0 DO
        SELECT IFNULL(`prent`,-1) INTO ch FROM
        (SELECT `prent` FROM Table1 WHERE id = ch) A;
        IF ch > 0 THEN
            SET rv = CONCAT(rv,cm,ch);
            SET cm = ',';
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN rv;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

A working ***[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f266e/2)*** here.

```
SELECT id,GetAncestry(id) as parents from Table1 where id = 7;

ID  PARENTS
7   6,3,2,1
```

Comment: thanks, may I know what `A` means here? `(SELECT 'prent' FROM Table1 WHERE id = ch) A;`

Comment: `A` is just an alias name for this result set :(SELECT `prent` FROM Table1 WHERE id = ch)

Comment: I recognize how cool this function is, however please can you explain how you would utilise the ancestry data in order to add it to a hierarchical list (its late and my brain is not firing)